# Проблема с алгоритмом

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Нужно построить алгоритм с временем работы O(mn). На вход подается список положительных целых чисел a_1, a_2, ..., a_n и положительное целое m. Можно ли представить m как сумму некоторых из a_1, a_2, ..., a_n? Каждое a_i разрешается использовать не более одного раза. Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    size_t t = 0; // число, которое необходимо представить в виде суммы
    std::cin >> t;
    size_t n = 0;
    std::cin >> n; // количество вводимых положительных чисел
    std::vector<size_t> array(n); // массив, в котором хранятся введенные числа
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i)
        std::cin >> array[i];
    std::vector<size_t> solver(t + 1); // массив, в котором я храню последнее слагаемое в разложении числа
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n && array[i] <= t; ++i) {
        solver[array[i]] = array[i]; // инициализирую подходящие элементы
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        size_t sum = array[i]; // sum - число, которое является слагаемым в разложении
        for (size_t k = t; k != sum; --k) {
            if (solver[k] == 0 && solver[k - sum] != 0) // если k-ое число 0, значит пока мы это число не получили суммой
                // и если k - sum не 0, значит k можно получить прибавлением sum, тогда оно последнее число в разложении k
                solver[k] = sum;
        }
    }
    if (solver[t]) // если это число не 0, то разложение получено
        std::cout << "YES\n";
    else
        std::cout << "NO\n";
}
```

Не могли бы вы объяснить, в чем ошибка в моем алгоритме?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот этот алгоритм (рекурсия, использую бинарное дерево):

```
int check_tree(int a[], int i, int count_a, int sum, int m)
{
    if (i >= count_a)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int new_sum = a[i] + sum;
    if (new_sum == m)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (check_tree(a, i + 1, count_a, sum, m))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return check_tree(a, i + 1, count_a, new_sum, m);
}

int main()
{
    int m;
    int a[] = { 16, 20, 77, 40, 55, 30, 70, 80, 120, 150 };
    int count_a = 10;
    printf("type m: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    if (check_tree(a, 0, count_a, 0, m))
    {
        printf("\nSuccess!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nFail!");
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Для простоты проверки я не стал делать ввод массива a с клавиатуры.

Comment: На самом деле я не ищу решение(вроде как рекомендуется решать через таблицу, в которой отмечаются позиции, которые достижимы при суммировании, соответственно при таком подходе возможно восстановление ответа), а пытаюсь понять, почему мой алгоритм работает неверно.

Comment: При любом подходе можно отследить ответ. Я вообще не понимаю логику вашего алгоритма. Можете подробнее объяснить? Как выглядит такая таблица тоже не понимаю.

Comment: В массиве solver на k-ой позиции последнее слагаемое в представлении в виде суммы. Я пробегаюсь по всем входным числам(для суммы) и прибавляю их к k, тем самым ставя на solver[k+new] = new. Таким образом, всевозможные получаемые числа отмечены в solver[k] и в них указаны последние слагаемые.

Comment: Не понял как массив может помочь. Допустим у вас есть начальные числа a[] = { 16, 20, 77 }; Что будет находится в solver[1]?

Comment: 0, а на остальных `for (size_t i = 0; i != n && array[i] < t; ++i) {
        solver[array[i] + 1] = array[i] + 1; // инициализирую подходящие элементы
    }`

Comment: Стало еще непонятнее. Читаю ваш код: создаем массив solver размером с m+1 (зачем? почему m?), затем идем циклом по массиву начальных чисел и в отдельные элементы массива по индексу начального числа помещаем число + 1. Т.е. получается что для начальных чисел a[] = { 16, 20, 77 }; и поиска числа 36 мы создаем массив solver размером в 37 и в  solver[16] заносим 17, а в solver[20] заносим 21 (ваш код: solver[array[i] + 1] = array[i] + 1;). Все остальные ячейки остаются пустыми. Зачем?

Comment: Да, спасибо, я ошибся с m+1. Если ячейки пустые, значит суммой мы их не получили(х.б. суммой некоторых).

Comment: Когда закончите, напишите пожалуйста ваш код или опишите алгоритм словами. Очень любопытно.